# Visual Studio 2015 not recognizing Windows SDK (Fall Creators Update)

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, uwp

I recently installed windows 10 software development kit for Fall Creators update (10.0.16299.15). I used the .exe installer from this link (Windows 10 SDK). But in Visual Studio 2015, while creating new blank Universal Windows App in C# or C++, Target Version doesn't show this SDK as an option.!

[image: See the image]

**Note:**  I use Windows 10 Home - Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.19)

Comment: For developing windows 10.0.15063 creator update and onwards required vs2017

Comment: and i am forget to tell you, you should also need to install/update to fall creator version of windows 10 on you PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 is required for developing UWP applications for Windows builds 15063 or higher, [see this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version).